# Tailwind default color classes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, tailwind-css

I'm building a **React** application using **Tailwind CSS Framework**. I have used **NPM** to install tailwind in my react app in the following manner:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Then I have also edited my **tailwind.config.js** file in the following manner:

```
module.exports = {

  content: [
  "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And updated my **index.css** file in the following manner:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then I tried to use default color classes that tailwind CSS provides in the following manner:

```
<h1 className='text-white'>...</h1>
```

Or

```
<div className='bg-white'>
    ...
</div>
```

But using this class is not changing the color of the text or the background of the div. Please, tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

For your kind information, I can use **custom color classes** by writing them in the **tailwind.config.js** in the following manner:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'custom-base-red': '#ff2f23',
      'custom-light-red': '#fb4a40',
      'custom-white': '#fefcfb',
      'custom-dark-gray': '#5f5f6c',
      'custom-light-gray': '#f7f7f7',
      'custom-border-gray': '#eeeeee',
      'custom-footer-bg': '#1d2124',
    },
    fontFamily: {
      'poppins': ["'Poppins'", 'sans-serif'],
    },
    dropShadow: {
      'custom-btn-shadow': '0px 5px 15px rgba(255, 47, 35, 0.4)',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Is your react file actually in the src folder?

Comment: Yes, my react file is in the src folder.

Comment: Your reply to an answer below says that your "custom color classes are working fine". How are you adding the custom classes? If you're adding them to your `tailwind.config.js`, could you show the file with those additions?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated the issue with my `tailwind.config.js` file. Please do check it. Thank you. @EdLucas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tailwind's default classes are not working because the custom ones you set in themes is overwriting them. To add custom classes move them into the extend object.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'custom-base-red': '#ff2f23',
        'custom-light-red': '#fb4a40',
        'custom-white': '#fefcfb',
        'custom-dark-gray': '#5f5f6c',
        'custom-light-gray': '#f7f7f7',
        'custom-border-gray': '#eeeeee',
        'custom-footer-bg': '#1d2124',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ["'Poppins'", 'sans-serif'],
      },
      dropShadow: {
        'custom-btn-shadow': '0px 5px 15px rgba(255, 47, 35, 0.4)',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: It's working !!! Thank you so much. That was indeed a silly mistake done by me. :) @Aaditey Nair

Comment: Glad to be of service

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is *import './index.css'* in the index.js file.

Also, make sure that You are editing the *App.js* file

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I have checked, there is import './index.css' in the index.js file. But I did not understand your answer's second part. I should mention that other classes are working properly. Just facing issue with the default color classes. But custom color classes are working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).